# How to check whether elements are identical in the list?

Tags: java, list, set

Is there a cleaner way in Java to confirm that all elements in `List` are identical?

```
boolean elementsAreIdentical() {
  return new HashSet<O>(list).size() == 1;
}
```

By 'cleaner', i wonder if we can do this without having to create a brand new object? Depending on size overhead may be substantial.

Comment: How are you defining "cleaner?"  In terms of code readability?  In terms of efficiency?

Comment: Define "cleaner". Ideally, you want to stop once the first non-identical element is found.

Comment: Make it `size() <= 1` so that it passes for empty collection as well. BTW your method is pretty clever!

Comment: It has a bad worst case, where it creates a set of equal size to the original list. I'd prefer something like `Object o = list.get(0); for (Object p : list) if (!p.equals(o)) return false; return true;`

Comment: Take a look at `Collection.contains`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (Collections.frequency(list, list.get(0)) == list.size()) {
  /* duplicates */
}
```

... for a list that is non-empty. Otherwise,

```
final int n = list.size();
if (n == 0 || Collections.frequency(list, list.get(0)) == n) {
  /* duplicates */
}
```

See the specification for [`Collections.frequency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29). This will be less expensive than your approach as well as others e.g. `Collections.nCopies(list.get(0), list.size()).equals(list)`

Comment: I think that only checks the number of times the first element occurs in the list. Not if all elements are unique.

Comment: side note: this method relies on comparison via a .equals method (see the jdk source code), so make sure whatever is in the list implements a proper .equals and .hashCode method (even though hashCode is not required for this, you should always override the two together)

Comment: @anio it checks whether the first element in the list constitutes the entire list in O(N) time.

Comment: @anio  He's not trying to find if all elements are unique, he wants to know if they are all the same.

Comment: @Matt that is a well-defined constraint in the contract for `List`. See [`List.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29), [`List.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), and [`List.remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29). :-)

Comment: @slavemaster Right, if let us say the list contains N items. And N-1 is a duplicate. Then you still need to loop over the list till you reach n-1 to determine you have a duplicate. Or am I wrong? See this: http://ideone.com/e4HDo

Comment: @anio I think you're confused about what is being asked. The task is to determine whether `list` is entirely made up of a single element (or other elements who satisfy `equals`).

Comment: @slavemaster Ah! Sorry you are right I was confused. I was trying to solve the more difficult problem of determining if every item was unique.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that a list of 1 billion same elements, except for the first one which is different, will take 1 billion iterations to return `false`. For that matter, a list with **all different elements** will still need a billion iterations.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you're correct. I was merely answering his question for a quick short-hand way of doing it :-)

Comment: @slavemaster  you'd be surprised how many people forget this.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an expensive way to achieve the result - in case of large data structures you face significant overhead both in memory footprint and CPU cycles. My first recommendation would be to control this when the list is created.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit verbose, but it has `O(n)` and `O(1)` time and space complexity, respectively, though it'll stop once the first non-identical element is found:

```
public static <T> boolean elementsAreIdentical(List<T> l) {
    if (!l.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<T> it = l.iterator();
        T unique = it.next();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (!it.next().equals(unique)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can be shortened using `equals`. Although `compareTo` being `0` does not strongly imply that `equals` is `true`, a `List` uses `equals` for comparing elements as a part of its contract (i.e. `indexOf`, `contains`, `remove`, etc.)... so it's safe to use :-p

Comment: For anything other than an `ArrayList`, this has dreadful O(n^2) performance. You really, really must use an iterator.

Comment: @Joao you need to add a `!` before your equality test.